# управление камерой при наведении в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

сделал скрипт для юнити на c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class camera : MonoBehaviour
{
private bool isMouseOver;
public Transform target;
void Update()

{
    if (isMouseOver)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(0, 1f, 0) { target; };
    }
    else
    {
        //В противном случае...
    }
}

void OnMouseEnter()
{
    isMouseOver = true;
}

void OnMouseExit()
{
    isMouseOver = false;
}
}
```

Повесил его на камеру а таргетом сделал виньетку и чёт не работает в чём ошибка .И если можно то как лучше сделать камеру при уводе в сторону.

Comment: Распиши цель, что хочешь сделать, так сложно понять, что именно ты хочешь

Comment: хотелс делать камеру как в стратегиях чтобы когда в одну из сторон мышку уводишь то туда камера передвигается как в warcraft 3

Answer (score 0):

События [OnMouseEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseEnter.html) вызываются для элементов GUIElement или тех на которых есть Collider. Там есть коллайдер?

Камера следящая за мышью:

```
Camera mycam = GetComponent<Camera>();
transform.LookAt(mycam.ScreenToWorldPoint(
    new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x,
                Input.mousePosition.y,
                mycam.nearClipPlane)),
    Vector3.up);
```

[Источник](https://answers.unity.com/questions/149022/how-to-make-camera-move-with-the-mouse-cursors.html)

Comment: Я не шарю наверное нету но что нужно сделать тогда?

Comment: Добавьте на объект, Collider или Collider2D в зависимости от того с чем работаете.

Comment: добавил круглый колайдер это я понял как физический объект получется?и раньше он просто не наводился на него верно.Всёравно не работает при наведении.И ему нужно присвоить родителя не behavoir а guiElemet?

Comment: Обновил ответ .

Comment: оо есть какойто результат только камера не передвигается а поворачивается и очень быстро поворачивается

Comment: за поворот отвечает transform.LookAt, можно полученный от преобразования (screenToWorld) использовать в любом месте.

Comment: Вот сделал чтото похожее но всёеще совсем нето нужно чтобы при наведении в угол камера двигалась в  ту сторону вот зачем я делал on mouseover  
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class camera : MonoBehaviour
{


    void Update()

    {


        Camera mycam = GetComponent<Camera>();
        transform.position = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, mycam.nearClipPlane);




    }
    }

Comment: во кажись истина уже близко кароче как вызвать камеру чтобы применить на неё трансформ

Comment: Если скрипт на камере то  Camera mycam = GetComponent<Camera>();  (это лучше выкинуть в старт)